# Solve $3x^5-6x^3=0$ (Presumably using factoring?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, factoring

I am to solve $3x^5-6x^3=0$

The solutions are provided as 0 and $\pm\sqrt{2}$ and I cannot see how to arrive at this. I wnet down various paths trying to factor the starting equation but that never got me anywhere e.g.

$3x^5-6x^3=0$

$3x^2(x^3-2x)=0$ # now what?

Also tried:

$3x^5-6x^3=0$

$3x(x^4-2x^2)$ # where do I go from here?

Is factoring the right path? How do I know how to approach this problem? How can I solve this equation?

Comment: Try factoring by $x^3$

Comment: Or factor out $3x^3$

Comment: Either $3x^3$ or $x^2-2$ is zero.  Clear?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have $3x^5-6x^3=3x^3(x^2-2)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! It looks so obvious now that I see it written. Sometimes I struggle just knowing where to start. Did you see the solution right away or did you experiment with different values for the first term $3x^3$?

Comment: I did what I always do in these cases: I have factored all I that could factor. And, since $3x^3$ divides both $3x^5$ and $6x^3$…

Answer (score 5):

Well, $3x^5-6x^3= 3x^3(x^2-2)$. This gives the real-valued solutions $x_{1,2,3}=0$ and $x_4=\sqrt 2$, $x_5=-\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Others have answerd regarding on "how" to solve this problem. Let me take a shot on explaining "why".

At a precalculus level, you have the following tools available:

- Factoring polynomials, and
- Solving second grade equations.

These tools are all you need to solve this!

As others (and yourself) have worked out: $$3x^5-6x^3=0 \Rightarrow 3x^3\cdot(x^2-2)=0$$ Now the question is, how to get to the solution, and why it works?

**Important:** Before revealing the answers below, make sure to work on the reasons yourself.

First of all, ask yourself this: If you have an expression in the form $A \cdot B = 0$ where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$, what are the values of $A$ or $B$ that let this equality hold? Think on this for a minute before revealing the answer.

> If you have an expression in the form $A \cdot B=0$ where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$, the equality holds if $A=0$ or $B=0$.

Now that you know the fact above, you can continue.

> Regarding your problem, you can apply this: $$3x^3\cdot(x^2-2)=0~~~ \Leftrightarrow~~~ 3x^3=0~~\text{or}~~(x^2-2)=0$$

By now, you can solve the full problem. Below is the rest of the answer:

> For the first part the solution is simple: $$3x^3=0\Leftrightarrow x^3=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$$ So there you have the first value for your solution.
>
> Now, for the second part, $(x^2-2)=0$, you can solve this using any technique you know for solving second grade equations. The easiest way is to factorize this: $$(x^2-2)=0 \Leftrightarrow (x+\sqrt{2})\cdot(x-\sqrt{2})=0$$ Again, this equality holds if any of the two factors are zero: $$(x+\sqrt{2})\cdot(x-\sqrt{2})=0~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~(x+\sqrt{2})=0~~\text{or}~~(x-\sqrt{2})=0$$ So the two possible solutions to this is $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $x=-\sqrt{2}$, or, more compact: $x=\pm\sqrt{2}$.
>
> So there you have your solutions: $$3x^5-6x^3=0~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~x=0~~\text{or}~~x=\pm\sqrt{2}$$

---

All other answers have provided you the solution, but that's only half the issue. If you *understand* **why** this solutions work, you will have the capabilities to solve **lots** of other problems. Always ask yourself: *What do I know that could help me solve this problem?*, and then try to split the problem into more simple things. That way, you will end up with:

- Problems you already know how to solve, and
- Problems that can be split again into more simple ones.

If you iterate enough times using this approach, you'll find your solutions 90% of times... and for the 10% remaining, you can ask for help, knowing that you have done all in your power to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$
3x^5−6x^3=0
$$
If you factor out *everything* you can, then it becomes very easy, since the second factor is a difference of squares:

> \begin{align}3x^3(x^2−2)=0\\3x^3(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})=0\end{align}

The roots are

> $$0,\quad\pm\sqrt{2},$$

the former with multiplicity $3$, the latter two with multiplicity $1$ each.